# TCP select function does not work for the 2nd connection

Tags: sockets

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 on a DELL E6400 with Windows 10. I'm writing a function to act as a server. I'm having trouble accepting a connection after serving a connection once. I have closed the previous connection. I used Wireshark and can see the SYN,SYN/ACK,ACK so the connection has logically been made. But my program does not come out of the select call (note that the first time goes smoothly and this problem occurs after I have closed the first connection).

Here is the gist of the code sequence "()" signifies it is a function call:

```
gethostname()
gethostbyaddr()
server_addr->sin_family
server_addr->sin_port
socket()
setsockopt()
bind()
getsockname()
listen()
FD_ZERO();
FD_SET();
k = select()
closesocket()
```

Here is the actual code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "EasyTcp.h"

//  On Windows, use Ws2_32.dll

/*  need to define some linux-only symbols for other systems */
#ifndef SOL_TCP
    #ifndef IPPROTO_TCP
        #define IPPROTO_TCP 6           // 6 usually = TCP
    #endif
    #define SOL_TCP     IPPROTO_TCP     /* tcp's protocol number (from /etc/protocols) */
#endif

#define LISTENING_DEPTH         3
#define MAXHOSTNAMELEN          132

void start_up(void);
SOCKET openserver( unsigned int server_port, char *server_name,
               struct sockaddr_in *server_addr );
int print_address(char *message, int len, struct sockaddr_in *addr,
                  unsigned int *host, unsigned int *port);
int print_ip_address( unsigned int ip_address );
SOCKET get_local_address( SOCKET fd, unsigned int *host, unsigned int *port);
int get_ip_address( char *name, unsigned int *host );
SOCKET accept_a_client(SOCKET listening_fd, struct sockaddr_in *addr,
    unsigned int *whole, unsigned int *fraction);



/*  Accept a connection on port local_port.
    Returns the socket or -1 if an error.
*/
SOCKET EasyAccept( int local_port )
{
    SOCKET     listening_fd = -1;      //  -1 when not connected
    SOCKET     fd;

    unsigned int sys_remote_port = 0;
    unsigned int sys_local_host = 0;
    unsigned int sys_remote_host = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in  target_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in  initiator_addr;

    unsigned int sys_local_port = local_port;    // The port to listen on
    unsigned int *whole_ptr = NULL, *fraction_ptr = NULL;   // The amount of time to listen
    char         *default_host = NULL;       // The host you want to listen to, else NULL

    listening_fd = openserver( sys_local_port, default_host, &target_addr );
    if( listening_fd >= 0 )
    {
        print_address("Listening", 1, &target_addr, &sys_local_host,
            &sys_local_port);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("openserver returned an error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if( (fd = accept_a_client(listening_fd, &initiator_addr,
        whole_ptr,fraction_ptr)) >= 0 )
    {/* accept succeeded, fd is connection to new initiator */

        print_address("Server", 1, &initiator_addr, &sys_remote_host,
            &sys_remote_port);
        get_local_address(fd, &sys_local_host, &sys_local_port);
    }
    else
    {/* accept failed */
        printf("accept failed, fd=%p\n", (void *)fd);
        return -1;
    }

    return fd;
}

int EasyConnect( int remote_port, char *remote_server )
{
    // not done yet
    printf("EasyConnect() is not finished\n");
    _getch();
    exit(1);
}


/*  Opens a new TCP socket for the server at interface server_name,           */
/*  port server_port.  Returns in server_addr the server's internet           */
/*  address structure.  The server is NOT connected to a client on return.    */
/*  Returns an fd that is a "listening post" on which to make connections.    */
SOCKET openserver( unsigned int server_port, char *server_name,
               struct sockaddr_in *server_addr )
{
    int                     len;
    SOCKET                  fd;
    struct sockaddr_in      address1;
    struct in_addr          address0;
    struct hostent          *node_ptr;
    char                    local_node[MAXHOSTNAMELEN];
    char                    *host_name;
    char                    buffer[64];


    start_up();

    /*  get the internet name of the local host node on which we are running */
    if( gethostname(local_node, MAXHOSTNAMELEN) < 0 )
    {
        printf("openserver gethostname: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        strcpy(local_node, "Unknown Host");
    }
    if( server_name == NULL )
        host_name = local_node;             /* default to local node */
    else
        host_name = server_name;

    /*  get structure for local interface server is to use */
    if( isdigit((int)host_name[0]) )
    {/* must be an ip address, not a DNS name */
        #ifdef __sun__
            if( (*((int *)&address0) = inet_addr(host_name)) == -1 )
        #else
            if( !inet_aton(host_name, &address0) )
        #endif
            {
                printf("Invalid IP address \"%s\"\n", host_name);
                return -1;
            }
            if( (node_ptr = gethostbyaddr((char *)&address0,
                sizeof(address0), AF_INET)) == NULL )
            {
                herror(host_name);
                return -1;
            }
    }
    else if( (node_ptr = gethostbyname(host_name)) == NULL )
    {
        herror(host_name);
        return -1;
    }

    /*  set up Internet address structure for the server */
    if (server_addr == NULL)               /* user doesn't want this back */
    {
        server_addr = &address1;            /* so store it locally */
    }
    memset(server_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    server_addr->sin_family = AF_INET; // node_ptr->h_addrtype;     /* should be AF_INET */
    server_addr->sin_port = htons( (u_short)server_port );
    if( server_name == NULL )
        server_addr->sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* use any interface */
    else
        memcpy(&server_addr->sin_addr, node_ptr->h_addr, node_ptr->h_length);

    /*  open an internet TCP socket */
    if( (fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 )
    {
        printf("openserver socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    /*  set this socket to reuse port addresses quickly */
    if (setsockopt( fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, buffer, sizeof( buffer ) ) < 0)
    {
        printf( "openserver setsockopt REUSEADDR: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
    }

    /*  bind this socket to the server's Internet address */
    if( bind(fd,(struct sockaddr *)server_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))<0 )
    {
        printf("Bind of IP address %s returned an error, port %d: %s\n",
            inet_ntoa(server_addr->sin_addr), ntohs(server_addr->sin_port),
            strerror(errno));
        //close(fd);
        return -1;
    }

    /*  now find out what local port number was assigned to this server */
    len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    if( getsockname(fd, (struct sockaddr *)server_addr, (void *)&len) < 0 )
    {
        printf("openserver getsockname: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }

    /*  set up listening backlog for connect requests from clients */
    if( listen(fd, LISTENING_DEPTH) < 0 )
    {
        printf("openserver listen: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }

    /*  we are now successfully established as a server */
    return fd;                              /* return fd of listening socket */
}


int print_address(char *message, int len, struct sockaddr_in *addr,
                  unsigned int *host, unsigned int *port)
{
    printf("%*s at IP address %s, port %d\n",
        len, message, addr->sin_addr.S_un.S_addr == 0 ? "any" : inet_ntoa(addr->sin_addr), ntohs(addr->sin_port));
    if( host != NULL )
        *host = ntohl(addr->sin_addr.s_addr);
    if( port != NULL )
        *port = ntohs(addr->sin_port);
    return 0;
}


int print_ip_address( unsigned int ip_address )
{
    struct sockaddr_in  x;

    x.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(ip_address);
    printf("%s", inet_ntoa(x.sin_addr));
    return 0;
}


SOCKET get_local_address( SOCKET fd, unsigned int *host, unsigned int *port)
{
    #if defined(__osf__) || defined(_HPUX_SOURCE)
        struct sockaddr_in  addr;
        int                 n = sizeof(addr);
    #else
        struct sockaddr_in  addr;
        int                 n = sizeof(addr);
    #endif


    if( getsockname(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &n) < 0 )
    {
        perror("getsockname");
        return -1;
    }
    if( host != NULL )
        *host = ntohl(addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
    if( port != NULL )
        *port = ntohs(addr.sin_port);
    return 0;
}


int get_ip_address( char *name, unsigned int *host )
{
    struct in_addr          address0;
    struct hostent          *node_ptr;


    /*  get structure for remote host node on which server resides */
    if( isdigit((int)name[0]) )
    {/* must be an ip address, not a DNS name */
        #ifdef __sun__
            if( (*((int *)&address0) = inet_addr(name)) == -1 )
        #else
            if( !inet_aton(name, &address0) )
        #endif
            {
                printf("Invalid IP address \"%s\"\n", name);
                return -1;
            }
            if( (node_ptr = gethostbyaddr((char *)&address0,
                sizeof(address0), AF_INET)) == NULL )
            {
                herror(name);
                return -1;
            }
    }
    else if( (node_ptr = gethostbyname(name)) == NULL )
    {
        herror(name);
        return -1;
    }

    if( host != NULL )
        *host = ntohl(*(unsigned int *)node_ptr->h_addr);
    return 0;
}


/*  wait for at most whole.fraction seconds to accept a connection */
/*  returns fd >= 0 if ok, -1 on error, -2 on timeout or control-C */
SOCKET accept_a_client( SOCKET listening_fd, struct sockaddr_in *addr,
                    unsigned int *whole, unsigned int *fraction )
{
    struct sockaddr     *client;
    struct sockaddr     local_addr;
    int                 len, k;
    SOCKET              fd;
    struct timeval      local_tv, *tv;
    fd_set              readset;
    char                buffer[64];


    len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    if( addr == NULL )
        client = &local_addr;
    else
        client = (struct sockaddr *)addr;

    //printf("Accepting connection\n");

    fflush(stdout);
    do  {
        if( whole == NULL  ||  fraction == NULL )
            tv = NULL;                          /* no timeout given */
        else
        {/* have a timeout, must set it up each time around loop */
            tv = &local_tv;
            tv->tv_sec = *whole;
            tv->tv_usec = *fraction;
        }
        FD_ZERO(&readset);
        FD_SET(listening_fd, &readset);
        k = select(0, &readset, NULL, NULL, tv);  // for Windows the 1st parameter is not used
        if( k < 0 )
        {/* select found an error */
            if( errno == EINTR )
            {/* return forced by control-C, treat it like timeout */
                return -2;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Select on fd %p: %s\n", (void *)listening_fd, strerror(errno));
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else if( k == 0 )
        {/* select timed out */
            return -2;
        }
        else if( (fd = accept(listening_fd, client, (void *)&len)) < 0 )
        {/* accept found an error */
            if( errno == EINTR )
                return -2;
            else
            {
                printf("Accept on fd %p: %s\n", (void *)listening_fd, strerror(errno));
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {/* fd is now the newly accepted connection from a new client */
            /* turn off the Nagle Algorithm on this connection */
            if( setsockopt(fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) < 0 )
            {
                printf("accept_a_client setsockopt NODELAY: %s\n",
                    strerror(errno));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    while( 1 );

    /*****
    printf("accept_a_client returning fd %p\n", fd);
    *****/

    return fd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for certain what's happening since your `main()` function isn't included in the posted code, but if I can assume that it is calling `EasyAccept()` in a loop, then the problem is that your `EasyAccept()` function is badly formed.

In particular, it appears that `EasyAccept()` calls `openserver()`, which creates a new TCP-connection-accepting socket, and calls `bind()` and `listen()` on it.  So far, so good.

Then, the problematic part:  `EasyAccept()` then goes on to use that socket to accept an incoming TCP connection and return the TCP connection's socket.

So why is that a problem?  Because when `EasyAccept()` returns, your program has "leaked" the `listening_fd` socket -- that is to say, the socket is still open, but your program no longer has any way to know what the value of `listening_fd` was in a previous call, so it can no longer accept TCP connections on it.

So, the second time `EasyAccept()` is called, it will try to create another TCP-connection-accepting socket, but this time the `bind()` call will fail, because there is already a TCP-connection-accepting socket listening on the port you want to bind to -- the "forgotten" TCP socket from your first call to `EasyAccept()`.

To fix this, you need to move the call to `openserver()` out of your `EasyAccept()` function; instead, call `openserver()` just one time at the start of your program's execution (near the top of `main()`, perhaps?) and keep its return-value around for the duration of the program's execution.  Then modify `EasyAccept()` to take that `SOCKET` value as its argument instead of `local_port`.  That way every call to `EasyAccept()` can re-use that one TCP-connection-accepting socket, rather than erroneously trying to create a new one during each call.